# Server view templates vs client templates with ajax requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, handlebars.js, pug

I am currently having trouble finding a nice solution for determining how/when to 'render' (generate html for) data on the server side vs rendering data via ajax requests on the client side.

Here is an example problem.

My client code has a search bar on every page that should provide a search result preview before the user hits 'submit.' The route for this is `/ajax/search?query=...`.

Once a user hits submit the client sends a request to the route `/results` and a results page is sent back.

There are two options I can think of and both seem to have pros and cons.

I can either render all the resulting html code using Jade (or some other templating engine) on the server as in the below call (done in Node.js):

```
app.get('/results', function(request, response) {
   var results = getResultsFrom(request);
   response.render('resultsPage', results);
});
```

Or I can instead send back a blank html page that looks like this:

HTML

```
<div class="search_results"></div>
<script id="search_result_template" type="text/handlebars-template">
   <!-- Client side template code -->
</script>
```

Javascript

```
    // Type should be of the form '/ajax/search?=...'
    results.url = "/ajax/search"+ $(location).attr('search')
    results.fetch();
    // Render the html generate inside the .search_results div
    resultsView.render();
```

Rendering on the client allows for less redundant code (my Jade template isn't doing what my Handlebars template can already do) and I have access to my data outside of the DOM (they exist in models, via Backbone).

Rendering on the server allows for one less call to be made to the server and the user doesn't have to wait for both the original page to load as well as a second ajax request to finish in order to view the results.

Any suggestions on a potential solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: do whatever feels best when wearing the user's shoes, don't worry about micro-optimizations...

Comment: @dandavis hmm, alright. I've decided to go with the second option for now, but I was hoping for some insight as to what is common or preferably 'best' practice

Comment: as evidenced by the crickets chirping, and based on my personal experiences, there's really no clear-cut answer. at least not yet. without that, fall back to other criteria on what to do; what's easier to maintain and better for your users? again, that matters on your needs and tools.